# Cocos2dx - Private bool when trying to use build_native.sh command

Tags: android, eclipse, cocos2d-x

I am trying to compile the class files in terminal using the ./build_native.sh command, however, after a couple of files along, it throws an error

```
cocos2dx/menu_nodes/CCMenu.h:59:10: error: 'bool cocos2d::CCMenu::m_bEnabled' is private

jni/../../Classes/AISBeganMenu.cpp:100:61: error: within this context
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/cocos2dcpp_shared/__/__/Classes/AISBeganMenu.o] Error 1
```

And then stops compiling, is there a way to allow private bools when compiling these class files?

Comment: what's line 100 in `AISBeganMenu.cpp`?

Comment: `bool AISBeganMenu::ccTouchBegan(CCTouch* touch, CCEvent* event)
{
    CC_UNUSED_PARAM(event);
    if (m_eState != kCCMenuStateWaiting || ! m_bVisible || !m_bEnabled)
    {
        return false;
    }
    for (CCNode *c = this->m_pParent; c != NULL; c = c->getParent())
    {
        if (c->isVisible() == false)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
`

Comment: well that's your problem.. `m_bEnabled` is private so you cannot access it directly. You need to use the appropriate getter.